# How to recover the record which is deleted from the table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a table(6 columns). It has 5 records.

Accidently I've deleted a record from the table. how to recover the deleted record now.

I've referred http://raresql.com/2011/10/22/how-to-recover-deleted-data-from-sql-sever/
this link for this issue.
Executed this query to get Hex value for the deleted record.

```
Select [RowLog Contents 0] FROM sys.fn_dblog(NULL,NULL)WHERE AllocUnitName ='dbo.TableName' AND Context IN ('LCX_MARK_AS_GHOST', 'LCX_HEAP') AND Operation in ('LOP_DELETE_ROWS')
```

got the Hex value: 0x3000.......

after that i can't get how should i split the this hex value. Anybody help me to split this hex value easily or give any other suggestion to recover deleted record from the table.

Comment: Just asking, has the transaction been committed or can you rollback?

Comment: please mention sql server version?

Comment: I assume you don't have a backup containing the data?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly why backups are essential if you can't afford to lose data. It's often a lesson learned the hard way, but if your data is important enough that you're going to try to go to extreme lengths to recover then you should have a backup of it.

As you have very little data in this data, I'm going to assume that it's either a learning/test system or that it's a lookup table. If it's the former then it would be very simple to recreate the data in the table. If the latter then you're either going to have to try to dig through for a backup or recreate the data another way.